# FM Radio app requires microphone permission "to capture the FM audio"

Tags: android

When I open the **FM Radio app** on my new Android **Moto X<sup>4</sup>**, it asks me for permission to use the microphone.

I realize that apps often require permissions for use in ways that one might not expect, and I would have assumed it was for voice control or such, but the explanation the app provided sounds unlikely and suspicious:

[image: "To reproduce a radio station, FM Radio requires the Microphone permission to capture the audio. Select ALLOW on the following screen to grant permission."]

Am I to believe that the application uses the microphone to quietly/internally record the audio of the FM Station I want to listen to, and then plays me back the third-hand recording?

Even if there's a feature to "pause" live radio, microphones only record *audible* sounds, right?!  Plus, wouldn't it be recording ambient noise "on top" of the radio audio?

<sub>`The device is a Moto X4, Android 9, Software variant amz/Amazon, Build PPF29:105-25-5. The "FM Radio" app that came with the device is version 02.02.0616.`</sub>

I had an old android that needed to have headphones connected for the FM Radio app for work, but that was because it used the extra length of wire as an cheater's [FM antenna](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Antenna_(radio)).

This doesn't make sense to me and couldn't get anywhere on Google (making me even more suspicious) with this so I was hoping someone here might have some insight.

Thanks!

Comment: Although you are concerned about security, this question isn't about security.

Comment: You don't link to the actual app, so we can't actually check anything out. You don't mention if you looked up the app's FAQ or documentation for what it means when it says that it "reproduces a radio station". The question you need to answer is why *this* app needs this access. That's a question for the app and it is not a security question.

Comment: @schroeder - Its not a downloadable app; it's one of the "built-in" apps included with the Motorola Z4 (and presumably other new Motorola's, if not all other Android devices that come with version 9.) I couldn't find any documentation for it and it can't be uninstalled.

Comment: @schroeder - I don't see how this isn't a security question... as in, why phone from a major manufacturer would be shipped with software that requires unusual **security permissions**.

Comment: Actually I found this FAQ which includes a link to the app but it doesn't mention the permissions: https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/indevice_detail/a_id/97362/p/30,6720,9050. Security is my *only* concern with this odd explanation of why Microphone permission is required.

Comment: Your question is why it would need a microphone. That's not a security question. As I said, that's a question for the app. You are worried about security, but the question you asked is not about security.

Comment: The phone uses the microphone cable as an FM antenna, so I'm guessing it requires microphone permission to access the signal.  The radio signal is very poor without the headphones plugged in.